# Is my AdMob ad unit id a piece of "private information"

Tags: github, admob, privacy

I don't know about this, really. I have never heard people talking about their ad unit ids, so I think it *is* kind of "private" and should not be disclosed?

Is my ad unit ids a piece of private information? What will happen if I *do* disclose my id? Is it ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, you should never share it with anyone or post it online. Someone could use your Ad Unit ID to spam requests and get your AdMob account flagged or banned.

Your Ad Unit ID also contains your AdMob developer ID. For example, `ca-app-pub-[developerID]/[adID]`. I'm not sure how that information could harm you exactly, but it is unique to you.

Comment: But why would anyone do that? They don't benefit from that, right? And final question - If I really disclosed it, say, on github, what should I do?

Comment: @Sweeper Some people just want to watch the world burn. Update the project on GitHub with a placeholder for the Ad Unit ID or remove the ad portion completely.